# S3 policy when using Codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codebuild

First, I'm sorry for my English. I'm developing a CodepPipeline using CodeBuild to deploy a React application to S3. It's OK in testing environment but when I deployed it on Staging environment, I got Access Denied error:

*An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied*

This happens because in Staging environment, S3 Bucket already got some policy. It goes like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront ABC"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3staging/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3staging/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "11.11.1.11/11" *VPN Address
                         .... Another Ip range (s)
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I understand that it allowed only request from CloudFront and deploy from the VPN Address. But now I need to deploy it from CodeBuild. So without modifying the existing policies, I tried to fix it by adding IP of CodeBuild from my area: 13.112.191.184/29 in aws:SourceIp in hope it will allow CodeBuild to delete and create file on S3. Sadly it doesnt work.

I tried a lot of ways like allowing CodeBuild's serviceRole's ARN but it also does not work.

```
{
  "Sid": "Stmt1599214911530",
  "Action": "s3:*",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3test-resopa-pwa/*",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": [
      "arn:aws:iam::123456:role/service-role/AWSCodePipelineServiceRole-ap-northeast-1-staging"
    ]
  }
}
```

Could anyone with experience help me in this issue. I'm really appreciate if just giving me some advice. Thank you very much.

Comment: No `Allow` will work due to `explicit deny` in your bucket policy for all requests not originating from `11.11.1.11/11`. How did you get `13.112.191.184/29 ` range?

Comment: @Marcin AWS publiced their service's IP Address here, man:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html#aws-ip-download

Comment: Can you run in your `buildspec.yml` the command to double check the public ip, e.g. `curl ifconfig.me`?

Comment: @Marcin Yeah, sure. I did. Happy that you have the same thought as mine. It turned out the same IP as the one I wrote: 13.112.191.184/29 ... But sadly, It doesnt work.... I will capture some image for you

Comment: If you add the ip range to the bucket policy, then you also need an allow. In the extra policy there is `AWSCodePipelineServiceRole-ap-northeast-1-noe-denki-admin-stg` role. This is CP role, note CB role based on its name. You need to allow CB role. Have you tried that.

Comment: @Marcin Wait oh yes ... Wait a moment, I will test it right away ..

Comment: Can you temporally remove the deny statement, just to check if it works without it? Also is `s3test-resopa-pwa` bucket different from `s3staging`?

Comment: @Marcin Sorry, but still no luck sir ...

Comment: @Marcin I just tried it. Remove the deny policy and it works just fine.... Sorry I just edited the bucket name so my bucket name does not get public-ed ...

Comment: So the Deny is blocking it. Are you sure that the added ip range is correct `13.112.191.184/29`, and that it shouldn't be a single ip address `13.112.191.184/32`?

Comment: @Marcin Yes, This is the IP which got printed out when I execute curl ipconfig.me on CodeBuild: https://imgur.com/a/5jipO4B

Comment: Dont have more ideas for now.

Comment: @Marcin Thank you for your support, sir.! Really appreciate it :D

Comment: @Marcin Adding extra policy doesnt work. I fixed it by adding these line below Condition:

"ArnNotEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::codebuild-role"
                }

Due to lack of knowledge, it took me almost a day z....z... Tks for your suggestion again sir :D

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked out eventually:-)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it.

```
"Condition": {
     "ArnNotEquals": {
          "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::codebuild-role"
      },
      "NotIpAddress": {
           "aws:SourceIp": [
                 "153.156.28.29/32",
                 ... Others IP Range
```